# Is two objects having same characteristics get stored in memory only once? Irrespective of the function in which they are defined are different

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class data
{
    private : 
        int i;
    public :
        data(int j)
        {
            i=j;
        }
        int getData()
        {
            return(i);
        }
        void *getObjectAdress()
        {
            return this;
        }

};
int main()
{
    data a(10);
    cout<<endl<<"Data = "<<a.getData()<<"  Objetc's address : "<<a.getObjectAdress();
    data b(20);
    cout<<endl<<"Data = "<<b.getData()<<"  Objetc's address : "<<b.getObjectAdress();
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
      for(int j=0;j<100000;j++)
         {
         }
    return(0);

}
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class data
{
    private : 
        int i;
    public :
        data(int j)
        {
            i=j;
        }
        int getData()
        {
            return(i);
        }
        void *getObjectAdress()
        {
            return this;
        }

};
int main()
{
    data a(10);
    cout<<endl<<"Data = "<<a.getData()<<"  Objetc's address : "<<a.getObjectAdress();
    data b(20);
    cout<<endl<<"Data = "<<b.getData()<<"  Objetc's address : "<<b.getObjectAdress();
    return(0);

}
```

[Image of output for the second function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvHWZ.png)
[Image of output for the first function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc2Qd.png)

Comment: This question is unclear. Do you mean classes when you say objects? No explanation is given in the body of the question. You simply pased some code (twice) which does not compile.

Comment: Do you mean you define the class twice but in different sections? Classes are not stored in memory... instances of classes are. And 2 instances occupy different memory locations, no matter what the class definitions of those objects are.

Comment: The above code are two programs written separately in two different file say pro1.cpp and pro2.cpp. In first program i placed delay function so that it continues to run and the pro2.cpp is compiled during the runtime of the pro1.cpp. And the result was    
   For pro1.cpp           Data = 10  Object's address : 0x6ffe00
                                   Data = 20  Object's address : 0x6ffdf0    //running

   For pro2.cpp           Data = 10  Object's address : 0x6ffe00
                                   Data = 20  Object's address : 0x6ffdf0   //terminated

Comment: Here is the link for the screnshot of output   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rLfs_M_oHDcmIp5qrmNXZOaPbGeQdISE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Here, you show two programs with the same `data` class, each of which creates two `data` objects.

The address in memory of an object in one of execution of a program is unrelated to the address in memory of an object in another execution of the same program, or the address in memory of an object in an execution of a different program.

In general, the exact value of `this` of an object is entirely arbitrary, and completely unspecified. The only requirement is that pointers to different objects that are alive at the same time have different pointer values.

In particular, objects that are alive at different times may have pointer values which output the same value when written to a stream.